# SparkSQL Fetch rows before and after from dataframe after grouping

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

Given this Dataframe  df

```
 +-----------+--------------------+-------------+-------+
|CustNumb   |        PurchaseDate|     price| activeFlag|
+-----------+--------------------+-------------+-------+
|          3|2013-07-17 00:00:...|         17.9|    0|
|          3|2013-08-27 00:00:...|        61.13|    0|
|          3|2013-08-28 00:00:...|        25.07|    1|
|          3|2013-08-29 00:00:...|        24.23|    0|
|          3|2013-09-06 00:00:...|         3.94|    0|
|         20|2013-02-28 00:00:...|       354.64|    0|
|         20|2013-04-07 00:00:...|         15.0|    0|
|         20|2013-05-10 00:00:...|        545.0|    0|
|         28|2013-02-17 00:00:...|        190.0|    0|
|         28|2013-04-08 00:00:...|         20.0|    0|
|         28|2013-04-16 00:00:...|         89.0|    0|
|         28|2013-05-18 00:00:...|        260.0|    0|
|         28|2013-06-06 00:00:...|       586.57|    1|
|         28|2013-06-09 00:00:...|        250.0|    0|
```

I would like to get result that returns average of price of 2 rows before and after ordered by purchase date when it finds an inactive flag '1'. Here is the result I am looking for:

```
+-----------+--------------------+-------------+-------+---------------+
|CustNumb   |        PurchaseDate|     price| activeFlag| OutputVal |
+-----------+--------------------+-------------+-------+------------+
|          3|2013-07-17 00:00:...|         17.9|    0|   17.9
|          3|2013-08-27 00:00:...|        61.13|    0|   61.13
|          3|2013-08-28 00:00:...|        25.07|    1|   26.8 (avg of 2 prices before and 2 after)
|          3|2013-08-29 00:00:...|        24.23|    0|   24.23
|          3|2013-09-06 00:00:...|         3.94|    0|   3.94

|         20|2013-02-28 00:00:...|       354.64|    0|   354.64
|         20|2013-04-07 00:00:...|         15.0|    0|   15.0
|         20|2013-05-10 00:00:...|        545.0|    0|   545.0

|         28|2013-02-17 00:00:...|        190.0|    0|   190.0
|         28|2013-04-08 00:00:...|         20.0|    0|   20.0
|         28|2013-04-16 00:00:...|         89.0|    0|   89.0
|         28|2013-05-18 00:00:...|        260.0|    0|   260.0
|         28|2013-06-06 00:00:...|       586.57|    1|   199.6 (avg of 2 prices before and 1 after)
|         28|2013-06-09 00:00:...|        250.0|    0|   250
```

In above example for custNum 3 and 28, I have activeFlag 1, so I need to calculate average of 2 rows before and after if it exists with same custNumb..

I am thinking of using  window functions over dataframe, but unable to get any good ideas to resolve this in spark as I m quite new to spark programming

```
val w = Window.partitionBy("CustNumb").orderBy("PurchaseDate")
```

How can I achieve this and is it achievable by Window function or any better ways of doing it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have window a simple conditional like this should work just fine:

```
val cond = ($"activeFlag" === 1) && (lag($"activeFlag", 1).over(w) === 0)

// Windows covering rows before and after
val before = w.rowsBetween(-2, -1)
val after = w.rowsBetween(1, 2)

// Expression with sum of rows and number of rows 
val sumPrice = sum($"price").over(before) + sum($"price").over(after)
val countPrice = sum($"ones_").over(before) + sum($"ones_").over(after)

val expr = when(cond, sumPrice / countPrice).otherwise($"price")

df.withColumn("ones_", lit(1)).withColumn("outputVal", expr)
```

Comment: Zero323. Thanks for the solution, but could you explain the lag function to find avgprice ? what does lag($"price,1).over(w) return and how is it taking 2 rows for price before and after ? I need to verify is same custNum exists for 2 rows above and below the activeflag row and then get average

Comment: Actually it doesn't. Somehow I misread your description. Please check an update.

Comment: Thanks for the solution though !! I modifed your old solution and got it working as well.. I posted it below, please let me know if this needs a fix !!

Comment: by the way whats ones_ ??

Comment: Just a column of ones so we know how many values we took. Otherwise we may take only 3 but divide by 4.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Zero323. You rock !! 
Here is my code piece based on your help I modified to get data what I am looking for in result:

```
 val windw = Window.partitionBy("CustNumb").orderBy("PurchaseDate")
 val cond = ($"activeFlag" === 1) //&& (lag($"activeFlag", 1).over(win) === 0)
 val avgprice = (lag($"price", 1).over(windw)  + lag($"price", 2).over(windw) + lead($"price", 1).over(windw)  + lead($"price", 2).over(windw)) / 4.0
 val expr = when(cond, avgprice).otherwise($"price")
 val finalresult = df.withColumn("newPrice", expr)
```

only thing I to figure out is, if activeflag = 1 exists in row above then I want to go one extra row above the row where activeflag=1. I Will try and update if I find workaround to get this.

Comment: Looks almost correct but it doesn't cover a possibility of a shorter window (only 1 following for example). I've missed that at the beginning as well. The simplest thing would to use `avg($"price").over(w.rowsBetween(-2, 2))` but it takes into account current row.